# NSManagedObjectContext merge from main thread to other thread

Tags: multithreading, core-data, merge, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I've used Core Data in various projects so I'm aware of how to deal with context merging from a thread to the main app.

My problem is that in a new application I'm working on I have a main context and a thread context that lives for the whole application lifetime whereas usually I created a context for each threaded call.

So I'm not sure of how to deal with cases where I modify objects in the main thread. Do I need to merge them to the context thread ? How ? Is it possible to ask the context thread to resync from the main context before each call ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification from the main thread and merge it where you need it. My suggestion would be to change your approach and do not do saves from the main thread. Keep the main thread away from database IO, and maintain the synchrony of the MOCs that need to be synchronized in the background.

Comment: That's what I used to do for long running tasks but I find it overkill to use a thread for almost instantaneous changes. I'd like a simpler solution. But I'm afraid listening for changes both ways will create some problem somehow

Comment: It's not an overkill. Grand central dispatch is actually a very efficient framework, and you can just use dispatch_async without much management to have a background thread and execute your code.

Comment: Well ... ChrisH solution actually provided an alternative that could work in some cases but I agree staying with classic thread approach is probably better so I'll choose this as the "right" answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the tasks that the other context is performing, it's hard to say what the best approach to keeping the other context up-to-date is.

You could try using `NSManagedObjectContext`'s `setStalenessInterval:` method, and then making sure that all Managed Objects you work with in that context get turned back into faults using `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` when you are finished working with them.

Comment: I was not aware of the staleness feature. Maybe I can try something with it.